Weakly convergence of a sum of random variables
Suppose you have two sequences of real valued random variables, say $(X_n)_n$ and $(Y_n)_n.$ If $(X_n)_n$ converges weakly to a Gaussian random variable and $(Y_n)_n$ converges almost surely to 0, is it true that $(X_n+Y_n)_n$ converge weakly to a Gaussian random variable?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Grammar nit: "Weakly" is an adverb, so it can modify an adjective like "convergent," but not a noun like "convergence." This should just be "weak convergence."

Yes. Denoting by $X$ the weak limit of the sequence $(X_n)$, the a.s. convergence of $(Y_n)$ to the constant zero implies using Slutsky's theorem that $(X_n + Y_n)$ converges weakly to $X$.
